# Leap Motion and Jakopter: missing LEAP_LIBRARY and LEAP_INCLUDE_DIR

Tags: cmake, leap-motion, ar.drone

I'm trying to control an Ardrone 2.0 with the Leap Motion. I choose to work with the project Jakopter which is a pilot script programming platform for Ardrone 2.0. I want to control the Ardrone with the Leap Motion and the executable which is doing that does not compile because of this error:

```
-- Checking for Leap
-- Could NOT find Leap (missing:  LEAP_LIBRARY LEAP_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

I looked into the `FindLeap.cmake` and I saw that it search the Leap library into `/usr/lib/Leap` which is good since it's were my Leap library is installed.

I have these libraries in my `/usr/lib/Leap`:

```
libQt5Core.so.5                   libQt5Qml.so.5
libQt5Core.so.5.2.1               libQt5Qml.so.5.2.1
libQt5DBus.so.5                   libQt5Quick.so.5
libQt5DBus.so.5.2.1               libQt5Quick.so.5.2.1
libQt5Gui.so.5                    libQt5Script.so.5
libQt5Gui.so.5.2.1                libQt5Script.so.5.2.1
libQt5Multimedia.so.5             libQt5Sensors.so.5
libQt5Multimedia.so.5.2.1         libQt5Sensors.so.5.2.1
libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5      libQt5Sql.so.5
libQt5MultimediaWidgets.so.5.2.1  libQt5Sql.so.5.2.1
libQt5Network.so.5                libQt5WebKit.so.5
libQt5Network.so.5.2.1            libQt5WebKit.so.5.2.1
libQt5OpenGL.so.5                 libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5
libQt5OpenGL.so.5.2.1             libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5.2.1
libQt5Positioning.so.5            libQt5Widgets.so.5
libQt5Positioning.so.5.2.1        libQt5Widgets.so.5.2.1
libQt5PrintSupport.so.5           libusb-1.0.so.0
libQt5PrintSupport.so.5.2.1
```

These come from the Leap package `Leap_Motion_Installer_Packages_release_public_linux` that I have download on the Leap Motion website and installed with `sudo dpkg --install Leap-2.3.1+31549-x64.deb`.

Because the cmake search in the right directory and I have my library installed in this directory, I really don't know where my error come from and why it's here.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. I have search on internet but I can't found the same error that I have, that's why I ask here..

I'll be glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no Leap library under your `/usr/lib/Leap`: your list contains only QT5-related libraries and `usb` one. But [FindLeap.cmake](https://github.com/tomcarter259/Find-Leap/blob/master/FindLeap.cmake) looks for library `libLeap.so`.

Comment: You're right, I get help from someone and we solved my problem by moving manually `libLeap.so` and `Leap.h` that FindLeap.cmake search in `/usr/lib/` for `libLeap.so` and in `/usr/include/` for `Leap.h`. Thanks for your help.